# Unable to reboot ubuntu after try create partition

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

I try to create a new partition from my ubuntu system and when reboot it shows the following:

```
error: unknown filesystem
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

I'm trying the following command to solve this

```
grub rescue>ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos1)
grub rescue>ls (hd0)
Filesystem is unknown.
grub rescue>ls (hd0,msdos5)
Filesystem is unknown.
grub rescue>ls (hd0,msdos1)
Filesystem is unknown.
```

Is there is a solution to recover the OS or should I need to reinstall the Ubuntu OS?

Comment: I would boot a 'live' system, check your drive health (using it's SMART; this step is probably optional & just my habit), then explore what is there (did you accidentally delete the partition (kde partition manager, gparted, gnome-disks etc).  If it IS there, I'd `fsck` (file system check) drive; if errors are found - it'll likely boot normally if you get this far next try (*with lucky anyway*)

Comment: @guiverc I accidentally delete the filesystem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu)

Comment: The duplicate link doesn't perfectly match, but the consequences are the same.  If you have some data you want to try and restore - the duplicate link will provide clues. It's a lot of work (mostly time), so I'd just re-install (anything necessary should already be backed up)